Optimize $a$ and $b$ for $2^a\times3^b\approx143$
I am interested in approximating positive integers with numbers in the form $N=2^a3^b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. For example, let's say that we want to approximate $143=11\times13$. We have,
$$2^a3^b\approx11\times13\Rightarrow a\log(2)+b\log(3)=\log(11)+\log(13)$$
$$a\log(2)+b\log(3)-\log(11)-\log(13)=0$$
The $\log p_1,\dots,\log p_t$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ (see), so obviously we cannot determine $a,b$ to have the above equation. I'm wondering if it is possible to optimize $a$ and $b$ to minimize the absolute error between $2^a3^b$ and $143$. Furthermore, I would be glad to solve this optimization problem in general case. In general, the problem can be stated in the form related to linear combination of the logarithm functions:
$$a \log (2) + b \log (3) + n_1\log(p_1)+n_2\log(p_2)+\cdots + n_k \log (p_k) = 0
$$
where the integers $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ and the prime numbers $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ are given and we want to optimize the integers $a$ and $b$.

I used a python script for $2^a\times 3^b\approx 143$ and the result was not so good. I looped over $a,b\in\{-10^6,\ldots,10^6\}$ and after about $35$ minutes of running, I got only two results for $|2^a3^b-143|<0.1$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & \text{Error} \\
\hline
825 & -516 & 0.05170246118419186 \\
-229 & 149 & 0.04546204418605271 \\
\hline
\end{array}
The python script:
from numba import njit, prange


@njit(parallel=True)
def fn():
    for a in prange(-1000000, 1000001):
        i_a = 2.0**a
        for b in prange(-1000000, 1000001):
            i_b = i_a * 3.0**b
            v = i_b - 143.0
            if abs(v) <= 1e-01:
                print(
                    "a=",
                    a,
                    ", b=",
                    b,
                    ", error=",
                    abs(v),
                )


fn()


Your script uses the line approximation technique, right?  So you start with some $a,b$ which are "close" to the desired result, and if it's greater you decrement one or if it's less you increment the other?  I think your script should be able to get through at least a couple orders of magnitude more with some optimization...

@abiessu I haven't much experience in optimizing the calculations, so I naively tried all the cases but optimized the code itself and ran it on Google Colab for its GPU.  I added the script in my post.

Don't iterate over both a and b.  Iterate over b and calculate the closest a.

You can use logarithm's to find the nearest $b$ for a given $a$. (Or vice versa as DanielV suggests)

The double-precision floating point format is limited to exponents in the range (-1022, 1023) for powers of two. Values outside this range result in either 0 or inf being assigned to i_a in your code.

@DanielMathias Oh, now I understand why I got only 3-digit outputs for $a$ and $b$. I will try alternative ways.

There is a generalisation of Euclid's algorithm to find (near) solutions to an affine linear equation $f(x, y) = a \cdot x + b \cdot y + c$ for some real coefficients.  It goes as follows:

For any two vectors $v, w$ such that $f(w) \neq f(0)$ let $k(v, w) = \lfloor f(v)/(f(0) - f(w)) \rfloor$.
Initialize three vectors: $p \leftarrow (0,0)$, $v_1 \leftarrow (1,0)$, $v_2 \leftarrow (0, 1)$.
Let $k_0 = k(p, v_1)$ and $k_1 = k(p + v_2, v_1)$.
Substitute $(p, v_1, v_2) \leftarrow (p + k_0 v_1, v_2 + (k_1 - k_0) v1, v1).$
Now the next near solution is the best one among the four vectors $p$, $p+v_1$, $p+v_2$, $p + v_1 + v_2$.
Go to step 3. and repeat the procedure.

Note that the near solution may be stable for a few iterations, but will steadily improve overall.  Here are the first subsequent different near solutions that are found for $f(x, y) = \log(2) \cdot x + \log(3) \cdot y - \log(143)$:



iteration
near solution
$\lvert f(x, y) \rvert$
$2^x 3^y$




1
$(7, 0)$
$1.1081$e-$1$
$128$


2 to 3
$(4, 2)$
$6.9687$e-$3$
$144$


4 to 6
$(23, -10)$
$6.5582$e-$3$
$142.0618$


7
$(-61, 43)$
$4.4942$e-$3$
$142.3588$


8 to 9
$(-229, 149)$
$3.1797$e-$4$
$142.9545$


10
$(17120, -10797)$
$5.8064$e-$6$
$143.0008$




I used @DanielV's and @DanielMathias's suggestions in the comments:
$$2^a3^b=143\implies a+b\log_23=\log_2143$$
$$b\approx\dfrac{(\log_2143)-a}{\log_23}$$
And iterated over $a$ to minimize the absolute value of the difference between $b$ and $\dfrac{(\log_2143)-a}{\log_23}$.
Here is the optimized code:
from numba import njit
from numpy import log2
from mpmath import mp

mp.dps = 50

@njit(parallel=False)
def fn():
    results = []
    for a in range(-10**11, 10**11+1):
        v = (log2(143) - a) / log2(3)
        s = abs(v - round(v))
        if s < 10**(-5):
            results.append((a, v))
    return results


results = fn()


for a, v in results:
    b = round(v)
    error = abs(143 - (mp.exp(mp.log(2) * a + mp.log(3) * b)))
    if error < mp.mpf('1e-8'):
        print("a: ", a, " b: ", b, " error: ", error)


It took $11$ minute and $51$ seconds to run this code using Google Colab's processor. Here is the output with the error term, $|2^a3^b-143|$, less than $10^{-8}$:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & \text{Error} \\
\hline
-97766741041 & 61683945837 & 0.0000000031507807699242165 \\
-87326880450 & 55097127167 & 0.0000000045983876908203010 \\
-77517158756 & 48907881876 & 0.0000000090896242338383130 \\
-76887019859 & 48510308497 & 0.0000000060459946117310390 \\
-67077298165 & 42321063206 & 0.0000000076420173130661400 \\
-66447159268 & 41923489827 & 0.0000000074936015326564330 \\
-56637437574 & 35734244536 & 0.0000000061944103922793130 \\
-56007298677 & 35336671157 & 0.0000000089412084535964800 \\
-46197576983 & 29147425866 & 0.0000000047468034714778310 \\
-35757716392 & 22560607196 & 0.0000000032991965506616947 \\
-25317855801 & 15973788526 & 0.0000000018515896298309042 \\
-14877995210 & 9386969856 & \color{blue}{0.0000000004039827089854595} \\
-4438134619 & 2800151186 & 0.0000000010436242118746395 \\
6001725972 & -3786667484 & 0.0000000024912311327493929 \\
16441586563 & -10373486154 & 0.0000000039388380536388005 \\
26251308257 & -16562731445 & 0.0000000097491738709566810 \\
26881447154 & -16960304824 & 0.0000000053864449745428625 \\
36691168848 & -23149550115 & 0.0000000083015669501911850 \\
37321307745 & -23547123494 & 0.0000000068340518954615790 \\
47131029439 & -29736368785 & 0.0000000068539600294110340 \\
47761168336 & -30133942164 & 0.0000000082816588163949490 \\
57570890030 & -36323187455 & 0.0000000054063531086162290 \\
58201028927 & -36720760834 & 0.0000000097292657373429740 \\
68010750621 & -42910006125 & 0.0000000039587461878067696 \\
78450611212 & -49496824795 & 0.0000000025111392669826560 \\
88890471803 & -56083643465 & 0.0000000010635323461438878 \\
99330332394 & -62670462135 & \color{blue}{0.0000000003840745747095345 }\\
\hline
\end{array}
The colored numbers show the error lower than $10^{-9}$.

$(-728988671138, 459940642642)=$ WolframAlpha is not as close as $(973610, -614275)=$ WolframAlpha

Also, my name is not Martha :o)

“Why did you say that name! Martha!”

@DanielMathias oh sorry fixed! Yeah, I couldn't filter out the closer numbers effectively in fact the code generates maybe thousands of these pairs.

@Prem It was actually a character named "Martha Huber" in the series Desperate Housewives. I think that name was in my head lol!

Oh ok , I was thinking about "Superman+Batman" Movie !

A different approach: python code Note: the accumulated error at the end is significant. The last value is unreliable, and the six before it have a true absolute error of at least $10^{-7}$

@DanielMathias Thanks for the code. I have edited and fixed my script maybe I try to iterate over $(-10^{12}, 10^{12})$ later.
